# Section block image alt text

Tags: shopify

When you use a image picker field inside a section block, if you double click on the image it pops up an option to include alt text.

How can I reference the alt text included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah nvm I figured it out.

It seems you just need to reference the image_picker id as normal and you can pull the alt from that!

```
{{ block.settings.yourImageId.alt | escape }}
```